# Set HTML table content instead of Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, metronic

I'm trying to add an advanced search to an html table.
So far with Datatable.js I managed to implement the regular search, but in the theme I'm using, I can't read informations directly from my html.
In the Js I'm using in the theme for the Advanced Search, the content of the table is loaded directly from an external php file, not the html where the desired table actually is.

How can I load the content from my HTML table and not from the url is the js (Ajax line)?

JS

```
"use strict";
var KTDatatablesSearchOptionsAdvancedSearch = function() {

    $.fn.dataTable.Api.register('column().title()', function() {
        return $(this.header()).text().trim();
    });

    var initTable1 = function() {
        // begin first table
        var table = $('#kt_datatable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            // Pagination settings
            dom: `<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>
            <'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7 dataTables_pager'lp>>`,
            // read more: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html

            lengthMenu: [5, 10, 25, 50],

            pageLength: 10,

            
            language: {
                'lengthMenu': 'Display _MENU_',
            },

            searchDelay: 500,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: HOST_URL + '/api//datatables/demos/server.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    // parameters for custom backend script demo
                    columnsDef: [
                        'RecordID', 'OrderID', 'Country', 'ShipCity', 'CompanyAgent',
                        'ShipDate', 'Status', 'Type', 'Actions',],
                },
            },
            columns: [
                {data: 'RecordID'},
                {data: 'OrderID'},
                {data: 'Country'},
                {data: 'ShipCity'},
                {data: 'CompanyAgent'},
                {data: 'ShipDate'},
                {data: 'Status'},
                {data: 'Type'},
                {data: 'Actions', responsivePriority: -1},
            ],

            initComplete: function() {
                this.api().columns().every(function() {
                    var column = this;

                    switch (column.title()) {
                        case 'Country':
                            column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                                $('.datatable-input[data-col-index="2"]').append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
                            });
                            break;

                        case 'Status':
                            var status = {
                                1: {'title': 'Pending', 'class': 'label-light-primary'},
                                2: {'title': 'Delivered', 'class': ' label-light-danger'},
                                3: {'title': 'Canceled', 'class': ' label-light-primary'},
                                4: {'title': 'Success', 'class': ' label-light-success'},
                                5: {'title': 'Info', 'class': ' label-light-info'},
                                6: {'title': 'Danger', 'class': ' label-light-danger'},
                                7: {'title': 'Warning', 'class': ' label-light-warning'},
                            };
                            column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                                $('.datatable-input[data-col-index="6"]').append('<option value="' + d + '">' + status[d].title + '</option>');
                            });
                            break;

                        case 'Type':
                            var status = {
                                1: {'title': 'Online', 'state': 'danger'},
                                2: {'title': 'Retail', 'state': 'primary'},
                                3: {'title': 'Direct', 'state': 'success'},
                            };
                            column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                                $('.datatable-input[data-col-index="7"]').append('<option value="' + d + '">' + status[d].title + '</option>');
                            });
                            break;
                    }
                });
            },

            columnDefs: [
                {
                    targets: -1,
                    title: 'Actions',
                    orderable: false,
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '\
                            <div class="dropdown dropdown-inline">\
                                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon" data-toggle="dropdown">\
                                    <i class="la la-cog"></i>\
                                </a>\
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm dropdown-menu-right">\
                                    <ul class="nav nav-hoverable flex-column">\
                                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="nav-icon la la-edit"></i><span class="nav-text">Edit Details</span></a></li>\
                                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="nav-icon la la-leaf"></i><span class="nav-text">Update Status</span></a></li>\
                                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="nav-icon la la-print"></i><span class="nav-text">Print</span></a></li>\
                                    </ul>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon" title="Edit details">\
                                <i class="la la-edit"></i>\
                            </a>\
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon" title="Delete">\
                                <i class="la la-trash"></i>\
                            </a>\
                        ';
                    },
                },
                {
                    targets: 6,
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        var status = {
                            1: {'title': 'Pending', 'class': 'label-light-primary'},
                            2: {'title': 'Delivered', 'class': ' label-light-danger'},
                            3: {'title': 'Canceled', 'class': ' label-light-primary'},
                            4: {'title': 'Success', 'class': ' label-light-success'},
                            5: {'title': 'Info', 'class': ' label-light-info'},
                            6: {'title': 'Danger', 'class': ' label-light-danger'},
                            7: {'title': 'Warning', 'class': ' label-light-warning'},
                        };
                        if (typeof status[data] === 'undefined') {
                            return data;
                        }
                        return '<span class="label label-lg font-weight-bold' + status[data].class + ' label-inline">' + status[data].title + '</span>';
                    },
                },
                {
                    targets: 7,
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        var status = {
                            1: {'title': 'Online', 'state': 'danger'},
                            2: {'title': 'Retail', 'state': 'primary'},
                            3: {'title': 'Direct', 'state': 'success'},
                        };
                        if (typeof status[data] === 'undefined') {
                            return data;
                        }
                        return '<span class="label label-' + status[data].state + ' label-dot mr-2"></span>' +
                            '<span class="font-weight-bold text-' + status[data].state + '">' + status[data].title + '</span>';
                    },
                },
            ],
        });

        var filter = function() {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
            table.column($(this).data('col-index')).search(val ? val : '', false, false).draw();
        };

        var asdasd = function(value, index) {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(value);
            table.column(index).search(val ? val : '', false, true);
        };

        $('#kt_search').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var params = {};
            $('.datatable-input').each(function() {
                var i = $(this).data('col-index');
                if (params[i]) {
                    params[i] += '|' + $(this).val();
                }
                else {
                    params[i] = $(this).val();
                }
            });
            $.each(params, function(i, val) {
                // apply search params to datatable
                table.column(i).search(val ? val : '', false, false);
            });
            table.table().draw();
        });

        $('#kt_reset').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.datatable-input').each(function() {
                $(this).val('');
                table.column($(this).data('col-index')).search('', false, false);
            });
            table.table().draw();
        });

        $('#kt_datepicker').datepicker({
            todayHighlight: true,
            templates: {
                leftArrow: '<i class="la la-angle-left"></i>',
                rightArrow: '<i class="la la-angle-right"></i>',
            },
        });

    };

    return {

        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function() {
            initTable1();
        },

    };

}();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    KTDatatablesSearchOptionsAdvancedSearch.init();
});
```

HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-checkable" id="kt_datatable">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>

                                                    <th>Record ID</th>
                                                    <th>Order ID</th>
                                                    <th>Country</th>
                                                    <th>Ship City</th>
                                                    <th>Company Agent</th>
                                                    <th>Ship Date</th>
                                                    <th>Status</th>
                                                    <th>Type</th>
                                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                    <th>2</th>
                                                    <th>sdfdsfs</th>
                                                    <th>sdf</th>
                                                    <th>sdfdsfsf</th>
                                                    <th>sdfsfsfsdfds</th>
                                                    <th>test</th>
                                                    <th>testtt</th>
                                                    <th>test</th>
                                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>33</th>
                                                    <th>sdfdsfs</th>
                                                    <th>sdf</th>
                                                    <th>sdfdsfsf</th>
                                                    <th>sdfsfsfsdfds</th>
                                                    <th>test</th>
                                                    <th>testtt</th>
                                                    <th>test</th>
                                                    <th>testtttt</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                            <tfoot>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Record ID</th>
                                                    <th>Order ID</th>
                                                    <th>Country</th>
                                                    <th>Ship City</th>
                                                    <th>Company Agent</th>
                                                    <th>Ship Date</th>
                                                    <th>Status</th>
                                                    <th>Type</th>
                                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tfoot>
                                        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the file: html-table.js
of: demo(n)\dist\assets\js\pages\crud\ktdatatable\base\html-table.js

There is a complete example of how to configure the KtDatatable. I think you are adding options from the remote data and not the HTML table.
Another way is the Local data, but the data is on a Js as an object